# Fetch content by HQL query

Tags: java, jpa

So here is the native query like:

```
select p.my_t_id from  tl t
inner join p p 
on p.id=t.p
where t.id=1
```

Entity structure

```
@Entity
class Tl{
 private Long p;
}


@Entity
class P{
      Long id;
      MyObjClass obj;
}

@Entity
class MyObjClass{
  Long myTId;
}
```

I am not able to figure out its `JPA` query..

Comment: make up proper relationship between your entities first.  If you don't understand why you need to do so, then I think JPA is probably not for you (yet).  Take a look to those SQL-based frameworks, like MyBatis or using Spring's JdbcTemplate

Comment: And your entity does not match with your data model well anyway.  What's the point of having `MyObjClass` while you have simply have an `ID` column in `P` table

Answer (score 0):

Since Tl and P don't have a relationship, you will have to use a Cartesian join.  See section 4.4.5 in the JPA spec: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf

I can't really translate your native query for you though, as you reference id columns on Tl and P in the SQL that aren't in your entities.  But read the spec and that should get you where you want to go.

Comment: The answer was to use a Cartesian join.  I can't really show the JPAQL with his entities because his SQL and entity definitions don't make sense together (the SQL references columns that aren't in the entity definition.)

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in comment, you gotta have meaningful entity model and relationships.

something like this (I am so sick of meaningless names, can you give something more meaningful?)

```
class Tl {
    private Long id;  // ID of Tl itself
    private P p;
}

class P {
    private Long id;
    private MyObjClass objClass;
}

class MyObjClass {
    private id;  // map to column myTId
}
```

The HQL will look like

```
select tl.p.objClass.id from Tl tl
```